# Rmarkdown knit shows 100% complete, but then after output file, showing error 99

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have use rmarkdown to knit, and it runs ok and shows completion of 100%. Then there is a line showing: output file: XXX.knit.md, after that, a error message shows and the file does not knit.

the error message is below:

File style.css not found in resource path
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 99

Comment: You are missing the file `style.css` in the source path. Even though the html is able to knit, the R markdown call on this file, hence cannot be able to completely knit